# Anaconda Error when installing matplotlib and nb_conda in new enviroment

Tags: python

I created a new environment in Anaconda and I tried to install Matplotlib and nb_conda in the new environment and I got the below errors. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with it? Thanks

[image]
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package setuptools conflicts for:
python=3.5 -> pip -> setuptools
matplotlib -> setuptools

Package sqlite conflicts for:
nb_conda -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.25.3,<4.0a0|>=3.26.0,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.1,<4.0a0|>=3.31.1,<4.0a0|>=3.32.3,<4.0a0|>=3.33.0,<4.0a0|>=3.28.0,<4.0a0|>=3.27.2,<4.0a0']
matplotlib -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.25.3,<4.0a0|>=3.26.0,<4.0a0|>=3.27.2,<4.0a0|>=3.28.0,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.1,<4.0a0|>=3.31.1,<4.0a0|>=3.33.0,<4.0a0|>=3.32.3,<4.0a0|>=3.30.0,<4.0a0']